# want to use sql count online people with begintime and endtime

Tags: sql, presto

I want to use sql count online people with begintime and endtime on presto。

my data like ：

```
userid  begintime   endtime
023150000030040 2020-03-05 12:50:46 2020-03-05 12:50:49
023150004186637 2020-03-05 10:31:19 2020-03-05 10:31:24
023150000788581 2020-03-05 00:59:01 2020-03-05 01:02:00
023150004411606 2020-03-05 19:55:42 2020-03-05 20:02:51
023150004066308 2020-03-05 18:48:03 2020-03-05 18:58:03
023150002033547 2020-03-05 12:39:24 2020-03-05 12:42:21
023150000030040 2020-03-05 13:26:02 2020-03-05 13:26:04
023150003690798 2020-03-05 02:04:50 2020-03-05 02:14:50
023150000030040 2020-03-05 13:57:10 2020-03-05 13:57:12
023150004460558 2020-03-05 16:44:48 2020-03-05 16:47:58
```

I want to Count people online every hour. Now I have a stupid way to count. My sql like :

```
select '01' as hour,COUNT(distinct T.userid)
from datamart_ott_b2b_jsydcp.f_tplay t where t.topicdate  ='2020-03-05'   
and t.begintime < date_parse('2020-03-05 01', '%Y-%m-%d %h')
and t.endtime > date_parse('2020-03-05 00', '%Y-%m-%d %h')

union all 

select  '02' as hour,COUNT(distinct T.userid)
from datamart_ott_b2b_jsydcp.f_tplay t where t.topicdate  ='2020-03-05'   
and t.begintime < date_parse('2020-03-05 02', '%Y-%m-%d %h')
and t.endtime > date_parse('2020-03-05 01', '%Y-%m-%d %h')

.......
```

Is there an easier way to do this? THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Prestodb, you can generate an array with integer values and then unnest them to get the hours.  Then use `join`s and `group by` to do the calculations you want:

```
select hh.hh as hour, cont(distinct t.userid)
from (select sequence(0, 23) hhs
     ) h cross join
     unnest(h.hhs)  as hh(hh) left join
     datamart_ott_b2b_jsydcp.f_tplay t
     on hour(begintime) <= hh.hh and
        hour(enddtime) >= hh.hh
where t.topicdate  = '2020-03-05'  
group by hh.hh
order by hh.hh;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a calendar table approach, we can left join a table containing all 24 hours to your current table on the condition that both the hour and date match.  Then, we can aggregate by hour and count distinct users to generate the output you want.

```
WITH hours AS (
    SELECT 0 AS hour UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 23
)

SELECT
    h.hour,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.userid) AS user_cnt
FROM hours h
LEFT JOIN datamart_ott_b2b_jsydcp.f_tplay t
    ON h.hour = DATE_TRUNC('hour', t.topicdate) AND
       t.topicdate = '2020-03-05'
GROUP BY
    h.hour
ORDER BY
    h.hour;
```